# How can a user avoid entering password on boot?

Tags: boot, password, login-screen

Is there a way to avoid entering a password in the process of booting up?
I am using a new and latest installation of Ubuntu, with Gnome desktop in it.

Comment: Do you mean before the graphical interface is loaded?

Comment: No. The password request is via the GUI.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set up automatic login?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5264/how-do-i-set-up-automatic-login)

Answer (score 7):

System → Administration → Login Screen. Unlock the dialog and choose what account to log in automatically as.

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed Ubuntu with the whole partition being encrypted. This will require you to enter a password before it can boot the system. If you want to avoid this, you should not choose the option for full partition encryption.

See also [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto)

Comment: How would I verify that the partition was encrypted? I tried the 

System -> admin -> login screen -> unlock advice, 

and the password is still requested.

Comment: You could boot from the liveCD and try to mount the partition. If you cannot do it, it is probably encrypted. It probably ask you for some information regarding encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the password request to unlock your keyring? If so, refer to this - [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)