# How to disable GNOME keyring?

Tags: gnome-keyring

I want to disable GNOME keyring globally on my machine. So I deleted the lines

```
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

in `/etc/pam.d/gdm`. It seems to me that this has no effect. When I lock in the syslog writes

```
Aug 24 18:37:03 foobar gnome-screensaver-dialog: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
```

and another user sees a menu window where he hs to enter his credentials. So what is the correct way to disable keyring for every user on that machine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this: **System ⇒ Preferences ⇒ Startup Applications** and uncheck `gnome-keyring-daemon`.

Comment: This has changed to just System -> Startup Applications, in Precise 12.04 at least.

Answer (score 13):

I think you just disabled the auto-unlock.  To disable it completely, I suppose you could uninstall it.  If that makes the package manager unhappy, you could also `sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/gnome-keyring`

Comment: The `pam_gnome_keyring.so` PAM module passes your login password to gnome-keyring after you login, which unlocks those keyrings that have the same password.  Seems like marking `seahorse` for removal doesn't try to pull other packages with it, so removing it should be safe.

Comment: Don't uninstall it. In Ubuntu 20.10 it will uninstall also `ubuntu-session` and `gnome-shell`, that would break your system

Answer (score 6):

For Gnome 3 (ubuntu 17.10 and later):

- ubuntu/windows key →
- `Startup Applications` →
- uncheck/remove `SSH Key Agent`/`GNOME Keyring: SSH Agent`