# Gnome Keyring keeps asking for a password that doesn't exist

Tags: gnome-keyring

When ever I long into Ubuntu, I'm immediately presented with a dialogue that asks me to enter the password that will unlock Gnome Keyring.

However, I was never prompted to set this in the first place, and none of the passwords I've tried are effective. How can I disable these popups and just have Gnome Keyring unlocked when I log in in the same way that encrypted home directories are automatically mounted upon log in?

FWIW, I'm set to auto log in, which may or may not be useful information.

Btw, I've seen this question: [How to disable GNOME keyring](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3045/how-to-disable-gnome-keyring), and the accepted answer didn't work. I'd rather not uninstall Keyring

**Update 1**: I've disabled automatic login but it still appears.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It only comes up on auto login actually.
To get rid of it :

- Open seahorse (aka "Passwords and Encryption Keys" in the preferences menu),
- Right click on "Passwords: login" (the first entry in the list),
- Change password : "Old Password" is your user password, then do not type anything in "Password" and "Confirm",
- then "Ok" and there will be a warning : "Use Unsafe Storage"

Comment: this doesn't work for me, I've changed to "Unsafe Storage" many time, and it keeps asking me for a password

Answer (score 2):

Thats easy, OK first follow these steps:

1. open your home folder
2. press Ctrl +h to view hidden files
3. double click on .local folder
4. press on share folder
5. look for key rings folder, right click it, and delete it.
6. reboot
7. you are going to see make a new key ring or default.
8. press continue and press yes to the other pop up box.
9. your done!

Comment: Spot on.  I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1