# What is default password?

Tags: security, password, gnome-keyring

What is the difference between *default* and *login*?
And what does **Default Keyring** mean?

When I run some applications(Emphaty etc), **Unlock Keyring window** launched first, then it requires me password. Why?

This is a screen-shot when I run Emphaty.
[image]

Why does it require me a password? It's a just messenger. It makes me crazy.

I was able to find this Window.
I guess this Windows could give me a solution.
Before trying something to fix it, I'd like know about what they are.

Please explain them to me.
P.S My login password is **not** equal to default password now.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Default' keyring actually means "the keyring called 'Default'" And it is a keyring automatically created upon user account creation.

That 'Default' keyring is where all the password goes, the Instant messaging app stores passwords, so it uses a keyring to store them. The keyring is locked so, to access it it need to unlock it to recover the passwords stored.

The password for that keyring is equal to the login password **until** you manually change one of these. So if you've changed login passwords now the keyring called 'Default' password is out of sync. Desktop uses your login password to try to unlock the keyring, if it fails ask you the password, assuming you've changed the keyring password.

Answer (score 8):

It's been a while since I've seen a default keyring - what version of Ubuntu is that?  Open up the default keyring to determine what applications are stored in there.  If there's only one or two, you might want to consider just deleting that keyring and storing everything in the login keyring instead.

[image]

It's possible that you have default keyring because your login keyring is out of sync with your login password.  Depending on your security requirements, you might want to consider changing the password on your login keyring to a blank password (called ["unsafe storage"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24770/gnome-keyring-keeps-asking-for-a-password-that-doesnt-exist/24773#24773)) which ensures that all future passwords are stored in the login keyring.

I'd only advocate this approach if a) you're using encrypted home or b) you don't care about security.

Answer (score 2):

You have recently changed your *user account* password, didnt you?

This is what happend:

- The "KeyRing" feature in Gnome is kinda like a "Vault" where credentials and passwords for apps are stored. Empathy, for instance, uses the KeyRing to store your IM's accounts logins and passwords
- Each KeyRing (you can have several) has a "master password", which is initially set to your login password. That "opens the vault", ie, allows apps to store and retrieve their recorded data. You were supposed to give the apps this "permition" by entering your `keyring` password each time an app request the KeyRing a stored value.

(thats what happening to you now)

- So, as long as your `user` and `keyring` passwords are the same, theres no need to do that, Gnome do it for you. Both passwords match, apps get their permition to store and retieve data without disturbing the user.

(thats what used to happen to you)

- But, since you changed your `user` password, but not your `keyring` one, now they dont match anymore, thus you are requested to input your `keyring` password for Empathy

So, to restore the previous behaviour, one thing you must do is **change the keyring password to match your user password**

Do that for both `login` and `default` keyring. Or, better yet, if you dont care losing all the passwords stored in the `default` keyring, just delete it. Apps may ask for credentials one more time, but you will have to give your (now synced) user password only once.

And check if the newly-created entry has really made it into the `login` keyring. If another `default` keyring is created again, then we will have to investigate further.

Answer (score -2):

Are you asking what is the GNOME keyring in general? This is from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Keyring)

> GNOME Keyring is a daemon application
>   designed to take care of the user's
>   security credentials, such as user
>   names and passwords. The sensitive
>   data is encrypted and stored in a
>   keyring file in the user's home
>   folder. The default keyring uses the
>   login password for encryption, so
>   users don't need to remember yet
>   another password. GNOME Keyring is
>   implemented as a daemon and uses the
>   process name gnome-keyring-daemon.
>   Applications can store and request
>   passwords by using the
>   libgnome-keyring library. GNOME
>   Keyring is part of the GNOME desktop.

Comment: This is best suited as a comment, Satuon, since you're asking a question of the original asker.