# Ubuntu 10.04.4 is asking for username and password during the instalation. Why?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is default password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26094/what-is-default-password)

I´m a beginner on ubuntu and I tried to install the program on my computer in the same disk with WinXP already installed. The program were downloaded from the ubuntu site and the image recorded in a CD. Please, tell me what username and password I need to use to install it.

Answer (score 4):

This would be *your* username and password - whatever you want them to be.  One of the things that make Linux/Ubuntu more secure is the requirement to have a username and password by default so that not just any rogue trojan or user on the other side of the world can install programs on your computer.

[image]

It's a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score -1):

Try username:

```
    ubuntu
```

with no password.