# Xubuntu: Disable gnome-keyring

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, gnome-keyring

I'm using Xubuntu, since GNOME and Unity are too heavy for my netbook.

I want to disable 'gnome-keyring' prompts.

I tried `sudo apt-get remove gnome-keyring` which results:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
    gnome-keyring oneconf python-ubuntu-sso-client software-center 
                  ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-sso-client-gtk xubuntu-desktop
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

and of course I didn't confirm that!
Because it will remove the whole `xubuntu-desktop` and `software-center` !!

Can someone help?

Comment: Software dependencies are fatal...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/24770/gnome-keyring-keeps-asking-for-a-password-that-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 4):

## UPDATE (with question)

Program `apt-get` on Ubuntu has fatal dependencies. Use **`aptitude`**

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude && sudo aptitude remove gnome-keyring
```

## Old

Install `seahorse`. That's `Passwords and Keys`. Some programs on Ubuntu is renamed, but packages is same.

```
sudo apt-get install seahorse
```

After that, go to **`Gnome keyring`** section and disable it (you can than disable it in Unity with `Passwords and Keys`).

Comment: So installing `seahorse` disables the keyring automatically? Is it some sort of black magic gig?

Comment: No, no. He wants program for disabling it. He know how to do it in Unity/GNOME with `seahorse`. I will update answer if you want...

Comment: @ZDroid Thanks! This brings the `Passwords and Keys` app to Xubuntu. According to my searches, I thought one can disable gnome-keyring with this app, but now I see this is not the solution. I will edit my question. My mistake!

Comment: @ZDroid I checked it out, and aptitude had no difference with apt-get. Aptitude also wants to remove both `xubuntu-desktop` and `software-center`.

Comment: LOL... I don't see any same.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. There's no "Gnome keyring" section. I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 64bit.

Comment: I added seahorse and I see passwords app.  So how to disable it from there?  Everytime I do hidden wireless, I get a keyring prompt.  I want to have it remember and not type any password.  Lubuntu 15.10 with xfce (openbox too)

Answer (score 1):

Seyed, this answer is just to address "Because it will remove the whole `xubuntu-desktop` ...".

`xubuntu-desktop` is a metapackage: you can take a look at [What are the downsides of removing ubuntu-desktop metapackage?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21497/25656). The answer is as relevant to Xubuntu as it is to Ubuntu.

I have a couple of references about metapackages which you may find useful even though they're not about Xubuntu:

- [Metapackages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages)
- http://www.mail-archive.com/lubuntu-desktop@lists.launchpad.net/msg03490.html

I routinely remove the desktop metapackage (as a consequence of purging unwanted software) because I always do a clean install and not an *in situ* upgrade to a higher version of *buntu.

In your specific case, it appears that not just the `xubuntu-desktop` metapackage but other possibly important software would be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Open System Monitor, in processes tab scroll down and select *gnome-keyring-daemon*, and click end process.

I am using Kali GNU/Linux Rolling and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in this post [1][Change keyring password on Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533324/change-keyring-password-on-xubuntu[1]):

tl;dr?

```
sudo apt install seahorse
```

This program can delete/change/create keyring-password. At least it was helpful for me.