# Change keyring password on Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, keyrings

How do I change the keyring password in Xubuntu?

I have seen instructions for Ubuntu (see http://www.ossdoc.com/2013/01/how-to-change-ubuntu-keyring-password.html), but I don't know how to find Passwords and Keys under xubuntu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The program's name is [`seahorse`](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Seahorse). If you can't find it in the menus, run `seahorse` from a terminal.

Right click on the keyring you want to change the password for, and select "Change Password":
[image]

Comment: I opened `seahorse`, but I don't know how to change the keyring password from there...

Comment: @becko have a look at the update.

Comment: just to add to this: seahorse is a frontend to gnome-keyring, among others. gnome-keyring should be installed by default; seahorse may not be (wasn't for me), but installing it will allow one to access these features. Probably irrelevant to OP, but in case anyone else finds this.

Comment: To add another option, in the xfce menu, look for "Passwords & Logins", which seems to be the same, if not very similar, app as shown above