Trying to change login password but new password doesn't stick
Changing it via sudo passwd said it was changed sucessfully, but when I log out and log back in the new password doesn't work. However it'll take the old password. So I tried sudo passwd (my prifile name) and went through the password changing steps, And it worked, but when the desktop loaded I was greeted with it saying my login password and login keyring didn't match. So it made me enter a password. When I tried my new password it didn't work. So I tried my old password and that worked. So I don't know what to do. I need them to be the same. (Ubuntu 20.04)
Edit: So I logged out and back in but this time it didn't give me the issue so what's happening?

Everything checks: sudo passwd changed the root user's password (which you might want to disable perhaps), sudo passwd <username> correctly changed your user's password; the issue with the keyring is that on login an attempt will be made to unlock the keyring using your user's password, but after having changed that the passwords don't match anymore. See next comment

Does this answer your question? Login keyring password "no longer matches"

Although I voted to close the question as a duplicate of the question I linked, I now notice that the answer is kinda meh. If you wish to keep secrets store in the keyring you're better off following the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/a/533326/380067

sudo passwd will change the root user's password, while passwd will change the current user's password.
Therefore, using passwd instead of sudo passwd would help.

You can reference to this post: https://superuser.com/questions/1512033/difference-in-passwd-and-sudo-passwd

u/Galaxium did not say if he used sudo, basically his question does not enough information. u/creeper12356 is correct that sudo should not be used. but I would not suggest to use sudo passwd for the root user either. better to first do sudo -i and then passwd as the root user, which are not the same.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
