# Is Gnome keyring safe?

Tags: password, gnome-keyring

I've always read keyring like Gnome-keyring is safe way to save credentials. I don't understand it. If I open my Gnome-keyring in my Ubuntu Desktop, I can right click any entry and click show password and it will show the password :O. My point is if I can do it anyone who can access my computer can do it. I can't keep my computer attended every second and sometimes I can forget to lock the computer.

I've set option to unlock keyring automatically at login. Without that I've to type keyring password every time the keyring has to be accessed. So its either type the keyring password or type the asked password. Now if I really have to type I'd prefer to eliminate the middle man and type the asked password.

So my question is, am I thinking/taking/doing this keyring thing in wrong way? Or is it the way it is? If its the way it is, how is it safe?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: I think you actually have a point. In my opinion to access "Passwords & Encryption Keys" one should be asked for the keyring password. An unlocked session is still a great security risk but it not justifiable to enable someone to get ALL your passwords and keys with just one click. Still agree with Jesse Glick's answer for the most part: http://askubuntu.com/a/112582/17789

Comment: Hi I want to show saved password on my keyring in Ubuntu 14.04 , but I am not able to do
Thanks for any helps
Frank

Comment: How do I "open" gnome-keyring? I only know how to run it as a command line utility.

Answer (score 15):

There is no special trick here; you are just responsible for keeping your desktop session locked when you are not sitting in front of your computer. Otherwise people walking by could do anything to your computer, even if you are not using a keyring of any kind, including installing a secret password-sniffing program!

Get in the habit of locking your screen whenever you get up *for any reason*. Do it even when you are sure you are alone so it becomes rote. This is quicker if you configure a keyboard shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for it (launch `Keyboard --> Shortcuts --> System --> Lock screen`). It would be nice if the Power control panel allowed you to lock the screen when a laptop lid is closed, but this does not seem to be an option.

And in case you forget, configure the screen to lock after a few minutes of inactivity (rather than going into a screensaver): Screen > Lock.

Comment: I'm really confused by this question/answer because [it says in the GNOME wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/SecurityFAQ) that gnome-keyring stores passwords using 128-bit AES encryption. Indeed, when I look at the files, they are encrypted. Is this answer out of date, or am I missing something here?

Comment: `seahorse` will display the plaintext, since it has access to the unlocked session, so the fact that the passwords are encrypted on disk is of no help if your screen is left unlocked.

Answer (score 8):

Keyring is meant to simplify your life by remembering different secrets (passwords), which are stored **encrypted** using your master password as encryption key. The encryption is a protection against remote attack (or if your hdd gets stolen or similar), because secrets are not disclosed in such case. If you disable unlocking keyring at login, you get only the advantage of typing the same password, instead of many different ones.

Comment: I think his issue is that they can be read back in the clear at all, especially using the default UI by someone just walking by without having to install extra software. Shouldn't these passwords be protected so that they can only e.g. have a hash generated against them rather than be read back in the clear at all?

Comment: @Rup: no, because these passwords have to be read back in clear whenever you use them.

Comment: How do you view the passwords in plaintext? I'm trying to see this for myself but am only able to run gnome-keyring from the command line so far as I'm aware...?

Comment: how does it matter that the passwords are stored encrypted? A remote attacker can just run `secret-tool` to decrypt and fetch the password, right?

Comment: @Born2Smile I had the same question than you then made some search and [answered this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1452386/258912)

Answer (score 1):

There are some key features which makes `gnome-keyring` a credential software with a certain level of security:

1. Centralizes and **encrypt** all stored credentials with a master password to help prevent unauthorized users from gaining access
2. The master password must be input in a pop-up screen which also will gain the computer user attention and make him realize some strange behavior that can be caused by a malware or something like, also make it more difficult to some automated software do stuff silently.

The caveat here is that based on `gnome-keyring` [philosophy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599749/why-is-the-gnome-keyring-not-locked-when-the-screen-is-locked), the master password will be asked once and cached forever, I did a lot of search and didn't found how to change this behavior natively, found an alternative though, to clear the cache every minute.

It will install a cron which run every minute and clear the cache:

```bash
$ cat <<EOF >> gnome-keyring-lock.sh
#!/bin/sh
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='${DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS}'
dbus-send --dest=org.gnome.keyring --print-reply /org/freedesktop/secrets org.freedesktop.Secret.Service.LockService
EOF

$ chmod +x gnome-keyring-lock.sh &&\
  sudo mv gnome-keyring-lock.sh /usr/local/bin/

$ crontab -u ${USER} -e 
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/gnome-keyring-lock.sh 2>1 | logger -t gnome-keyring-lock

$<ESC>:wq
```

You can check the logs by typing:

```bash
$ tail  -f /var/log/syslog | grep gnome-keyring-lock
Jan 28 18:17:01 typer-pc gnome-keyring-lock: method return time=1674940621.720454 sender=:1.50 -> destination=:1.163 serial=204 reply_serial=2
```

This way the master password will be asked next time something try to recover some credential to gnome-keyring, keep in mind security and comfort are not friends, ask the master password every single time a credential is needed, probably won't last, cache them forever also doesn't sound like a good idea, despite the fact a computer connected to the internet will never be 100% secure, yes, gnome-keyring will help to keep the passwords more secure than just save them to a plain text file anywhere on your hard drive.

References

- [How can I adjust the default passphrase caching duration for GPG/PGP/SSH keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340809/how-can-i-adjust-the-default-passphrase-caching-duration-for-gpg-pgp-ssh-keys)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449218/gnome-keyring-stays-unlocked-permanently
- https://superuser.com/questions/700826/how-to-lock-a-unlocked-gnome-keyring
- [How to disable GNOME keyring?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3045/how-to-disable-gnome-keyring)
- [How to recover/reset forgotten Gnome Keyring Password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password)
- https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-change-the-gnome-keyring-password/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-can-i-save-username-and-password-in-git
- [How to recover/reset forgotten Gnome Keyring Password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password)

Comment: Yes, clearing the password after a duration as you suggest would be a must have :) The part about the popup is wrong though, `secret-tool` does not launch a popup. It can be run via script in the background. Also, while the key chain is unlocked, all the passwords are freely available, not just the one that was needed. The encryption only matters when the key chain is locked :(

Answer (score -6):

The keyring uses weak encryption, yeah, weak. A simple password to unlock all your passwords? That's a joke in term of security. But it's easy to use, so a lot of people like it.

The common Joe or Alice (family, friends, co-workers) will not be able to decrypt it easily. If you want to protect your passwords against them, well. Keyring is safe.

Now, if someone with a degree in math, encryption, or a hacker is decided to get your passwords they will do it after a few days or weeks (or months if they are really unlucky).

And if the IRS gets you computer, well they can get a hand on the strong servers to get your passwords in a matter of minutes. Same for:

- FBI
- CIA
- NSA
- Mossad
- ASIS
- RAW
- DGSE
- FSB
- BND
- MSS
- MI-6
- ISI

So, is it safe? Well, it depends upon you and your needs.

Comment: What is your proof of this "uses weak encryption"? Do you know how much time a typical computer needs to break such encryption key or even break it at all.

Comment: `gnome-keyring` uses [AES-128](http://superuser.com/questions/328011/encryption-algorithm-of-gnome-keyring), which as of this date is computationally unfeasible to break other than by a brute force/dictionary attack.

Comment: @Vladimir Please provide proof that AES is unsafe against the FBI/CIA/etc and I'll give this a +1 and ask my friends to +1 it too. Also you'll likely win the nobel peace prize.

Comment: I don't feel this post should have been so heavily down-voted. Seems to me that Vladimir is trying to raise a legitimate concern even if he may have had trouble communicating that concern. While unrelated to what Vladimir is saying, I recently ran across a post by @Bruno Pereira here that has me troubled...
https://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password
I may be missing something but it seems to talk of a way to potentially retrieve keys in the ring *without* having to know the master password...  Am I just confused?

Comment: @aggregate1166877 - Isn't this "proof" enough that AES-128 is unsafe against FBI/CIA/CCP (Communist Party of China) etc?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOP500#TOP_500
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing#Cryptography

Comment: @ShawnEary The idea with cryptographic systems is not to keep them at the same strength over decades. As computational power increases, your OS default settings will have larger block sizes each release. If quantum computers become a problem, we'll likely have something like AES-8192 to compensate. Having said that, yes, cryptographic systems (especially key-pair setups) are extremely weak to quantum breakers. I believe the reason for all the downvotes here is airheaded fearmongering with nothing to back it up. Security is important, but fearmongering causes more problems that it solves.