# How can I adjust the default passphrase caching duration for GPG/PGP/SSH keys?

Tags: ssh, gnupg, keyrings, seahorse, pgp

As far as I know, `gnome-keyring-daemon` caches passphrases for keys by default until I log out. I would like to set the default to something like "cache for 10 minutes". How can I do that in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found related options in ´gsettings´ under ´org.gnome.crypto.cache´. Unfortunately these do not seem to have any effect. Probably this is due to this bug for which the fixes apparently were never merged to ubuntu (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=681081)

Comment: OK, the last comment is only true for SSH-keys. For GPG the settings work as expected.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- Lauch `dconf-editor`.
- Navigate to **desktop - gnome - crypto - cache**.
- change `gpg-cache-method` to `idle` or `timeout`.
- change `gpg-cache-ttl` to the number of seconds you want the passphrase to be cached.
- Restart the gnome-keyring daemon `$ gnome-keyring-daemon -r`

`idle` means that the timer is reset each time you use the key *before* timeout is reached. `timeout` means that simply the time elapsed since entering the passphrase is considered.

This *only* works for GPG-keys. Passphrases for SSH-keys are still cached until the end of the session. IMHO this is a bug.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it made no difference. The system remembers the passphrase regardless and decryption follows. This is a serious security issue. I am surprised nobody has raised a red flag.

Comment: I'm struggling with this problem under Ubuntu 18.03. I used dconf-editor to change to `timeout` and use 1 second. I reset the keyring and immediately after I had to use the password for my PGP key. However, once entered, the password gets cached again. It survives a reboot/logout. Very frustrating!

Comment: If not mistaken, the command line equivalent is: `gsettings set org.gnome.crypto.cache gpg-cache-method 'timeout'`, `gsettings set org.gnome.crypto.cache gpg-cache-ttl 300`, `gnome-keyring-daemon -r`.

Comment: I also agree that cache credentials forever (not the session, in my case, don't know got to change this) don't make sense for a tool which is made to increase security, [created a workaround for it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1452386/258912)

Comment: Does someone know about `session` as value for `gpg-cache-method` ?