# Don't remember PGP passphrase until end of session

Tags: security, gnupg, seahorse, pgp

To use my PGP key I always have to enter my passphrase. But as it happens, I have to unlock the key only once for every session. The desired behaviour would be, that I have to unlock the key *each time* I want to use it so the passphrase is not remembered for the whole session.

The dialog for entering the passphrase provides a checkbox "Automatically unlock this key, whenever I'm logged in" but that is also not what I want. I recall this dialog in older versions of Ubuntu providing more options, like this:

[image]

But these options are never provided to me. So how can I configure Seahorse/GPG/Ubuntu to always locking the key after usage?

Comment: Searching for "cache gpg" would have helped you find existing answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings for Seahorse are in 'gsettings': `gpg-cache-method` and `gpg-cache-ttl`. Answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/358514/194774).

If you preffer, you could also have 'gpg-agent' manage the keys, check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/381221/194774).

Answer (score 1):

This can be configured by editing `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`. Two options are of interest, `default-cache-ttl` is the time after using the key until it gets locked, `max-cache-ttl` is the time after unlocking the key.

`man gpg-agent` does not describe whether a `max-cache-ttl` value of `0` disables caching completely (as it invalidates instantly) or disables invalidation, but you will be able to realize easily. If not, think about setting it to `1` (seconds).

```
max-cache-ttl 0
```

Comment: I fear this approach doesn't work since I'm using Seahorse for key management.