# Google Chrome password

Tags: sound, google-chrome

I have not used Ubuntu in a few years, the reason is that I use SketchUp and there is no version for linux base.  Also I have a Sound Blaster ZXR DBPro sound card and it doesn't work.  Soon, I believe, Windows will stop offering support to W7 (my OS), with what I hear about W10, I really don't want to install it mostly due to privacy issues.  I also have MY Office 2010.

Recently I have booted on Ubuntu, Chrome is already installed but when I clicked on it I have a box that demands that I enter a password to access.  First I don't recall setting up a password for this application.  Second, once this popup happens I cannot get rid of it.  Annoying, really.

Anyone can tip me on this issue?

Thank you.

Pat.

Comment: Do you have automatic access? If so, put the user password. This will allow Chrome to use unlock the local keyring to safely store and use your passwords from there. If you do not want to store the passwords, you can simply [disable the keyring](http://askubuntu.com/a/3104/29595).

Comment: I just click to close the window whenever it pops up.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier just to reset chrome for your logged in account.

Once you've done this, you'll be able to restart chrome afresh and use the chrome sync option to reimport your websites and passwords etc from windows (assuming of course you are using chrome on windows).

Launch a terminal from dash or the keyboard combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
```