# Remove Keyring Popup on Startup

Tags: login, password, keyrings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyring On Startup popup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80251/keyring-on-startup-popup)

I forgot my password recently, so I had to use Ubuntu's recovery mode to change it to something else. I used this command: `passwd username` and I was then prompted for the new password. Then I rebooted and logged in. Everything went very smoothly, except that now everytime I log in  I see this pop-up 3 times before I can do anything else:

[image: Very Annoying!]

I've tried entering my current password but that doesn't work. How can I get this annoying pop-up to stop showing up? I looked at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot) however the checkbox to make this connection available to all users is disabled for me.

Comment: The gnome keyring is a secure storage system for passwords and keys. It needs a master password to encrypt the data. When a user is created the gnome keyring password is set to the user's login password value. To avoid being prompted for a password, when you change the user's login password you must change the gnome keyring password accordingly.

Comment: Oli, you merged http://askubuntu.com/questions/28698/why-am-i-asked-for-a-password-after-automatic-login with this question. This is not an exact duplicate at all!! The question you closed asked for the reason why the keyring dialogue pops up, this one asks how to get rid of it. That is completely different. I would like to ask you to revert your merge.

Comment: The more even, you asked really exactly the same question before here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot Please rather merge these two.

Comment: @Ingo I won't revert the merge. A good answer will explain both what the problem is and how to fix it. More importantly, these two threads are both part of the bug that you mention. Your answer does apply to this thread, just as much as it applied to the last one (hence the merge instead of a straight close). This thread already mentions that [my thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot) doesn't help them and I believe that has more to do with my issue being slightly different (so I'm reluctant to merge this further).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Open your Home Folder(Places>>Home Folder )
- Press **Ctrl+H** to view hidden files.
- Open **.gnome2** folder and then **keyrings** folder and delete **login.keyring** file.
- Reboot the system.
- The pop-up will be disappeared now.

Comment: Please note that you may lose passwords stored your login keyring, but if you can't remember the previous login password you will not be able to recover them anyway.

Comment: I have no keyrings folder...

Comment: I just found the file in a different location: `~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring`

Answer (score 5):

The system asks you to "Unlock your keyring" because it wants to access some passwords that are stored on your computer. This could be, for example, the password to connect to your wireless network. See it as an extra protection: The system wants to make sure that you in person allow programs accessing passwords.

On the other hand, as you mention it is quite a paradox behavior. After all you selected that you do *not* want to enter a password on login. So the reasoning above makes only half sense.

In fact, this wrong system behavior has already been identified by the developers. There is [Bug #553646](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/553646) on Ubuntu's bug tracking platform Launchpad which you can follow to see progress made.

If you sign up on Launchpad and select "This bug affects me too" you can contribute to raise attention for this bug :).

Answer (score 1):

You could just change the password on the keyring.  See [this blog post](http://www.code-muse.com/blog/?p=53) for information on accomplishing just that.

Answer (score 0):

It is also important to set 'login' keyring as `default`. Right click on key ring and choose `set as default`. After that 'default keyring' can be removed. Of course this removes all passwords that were stored in keyring but for my it's good enough.