# Why am I asked for a password after automatic login?

Tags: gnome, login, automatic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyring On Startup popup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80251/keyring-on-startup-popup)

I use automatic login because I don't want to enter a password every time I start the system. Although automatic login works, I'm still asked for my password after the desktop is loaded (I need to enter it three times). How can I fix this?