# Keyring On Startup popup

Tags: keyrings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

Every time when i reboot my pc keyring ask for password!

What i want to do is that i dont want to type password every time my pc start

i want to to auto-login password and dont ask me for password

& Dont want to [Delete the login.keyring](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17353/remove-keyring-popup-on-startup)

I want it to auto-login (i think its abt ubuntu one > keyring )

[keyring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyZ0W.jpg)