# An application asks to unlock the keyring on startup, but it doesn't say which one

Tags: seahorse

A couple of weeks ago a popup has appeared whenever I startup telling me that an application wants to access the keyring but it doesn't say which one. I'm used to seeing the application name on the popup but here it just says 'application'.

I haven't changed any passwords or did anything that might have something to do with that, 
to my knowledge.

I saw this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot) but like I said, I haven't changed any of my passwords, and I don't want my keyring password to be empty.

How can I find out which application is asking to unlock the keyring and fix it?

Here's how it looks like:
[image]

Comment: What version of ubuntu you are using?And can you post us the snapshot of the popup window?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10. And that's a negative about the snapshot, it doesn't work. The print screen key nor any of the menus seem locked.

Comment: I can take a picture of it using a camera if you think that'll help though.

Comment: what application have you installed lately that requires a password..If you joining a wireless network , make sure "available to all users is checked"..

Comment: I don't think I've installed anything lately that requires a password. And I'm not joining a wireless network.

Comment: do you autologin?

Comment: @DKuntz: yes, since the very first time I installed Ubuntu

Comment: It would really help to know the exact wording of the prompt.

Comment: @Idan K - it really is nm-applet and possibly anything else you have installed that needs keyring.  upping proof video to vimeo in a couple of hours...already tested it and I'm SURE.  i'll put the link in an edit.

Comment: @aking: then I don't understand what changed with the network manager that it recently started to ask for the password. if it is the nm-applet, how do I fix it?

Comment: you can disable it or use a script to unlock your keyring earlier in your boot process as detailed on the link i added in my edit

Comment: as to what changed, most users experiencing the problem that i can find indicate that it happens after a dist-upgrade package update that makes nm-applet want keyring access. as to the fellow on U/L that said "I cancel and it still connects" he's probably using open wireless or a wired connection.

Comment: the upstream bug is logged at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=574315 - I've requested comments from the developers here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I setup my box for auto-login and it does this on every login.  In my case it's nm-applet/network-manager family of apps.

edit:
btw the problem has been around for some time, evidently some half-fix got undone during a package upgrade, but i digress...one solution is [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=320308)

WHATEVER is causing the problem you could add after login but before everything else: a script with libpam-gnome-keyring to unlock it...the package to get this tool is: libpam-gnome-keyring at least in 11.04

```
#!/bin/bash  
#launch useful stuff for gnome
#first unlock the default keyring...  
echo YOUR_KEYRING_PASSWORD_HERE | /usr/libexec/pam-keyring-tool -u -s  
#then run nm-applet in the background...  
nm-applet &
```

and the "bugs" on bugzilla are probably being continually given priority of low because it's only for autologin users.  it doesn't happen "out of the box" only due to customization.  just trying to help you understand why it seems like the devs don't care.  it's not a coding problem, it's...well...something else.

proof video that it is nm-applet is [here](http://vimeo.com/19350519)

and the reason it freezes the menu system is not because of gksudo, it's because it's an applet trying to start that grabs the tray and locks the menu-system.  at least in my case you can still launch icons on the desktop.  try putting a shortcut to a terminal there if you really must go mucking about with the prompt there.

Comment: I've been auto logging since forever. How do you know which app is causing it in your case? Can I somehow check what's causing it in my setup?

Comment: np, just upsetting that i knew i was right and didn't get the bounty...but oh well.  didn't meet the time constraint

Comment: I'd give you the rest of my rep if I could, if that comforts you ;)

Comment: again np.  i could have done this digging before it expired and i didn't.  my fault

Answer (score 7):

From a security perspective, the answer is that in current distros (not just Ubuntu) you can't tell which application it is. See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=574315#c4 for clarification from a gnome-keyring developer, including the security implications and scope of the task. See also http://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring/SecurityPhilosophy

(From a practical perspective I am also using auto-login on Ubuntu, and it seems that it is indeed nm-applet.)

Answer (score 2):

I have found:

- A similar question on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/how-can-i-tell-which-application-is-asking-for-access-to-gnome-keyring-seahorse).
- Several bug reports ([[image]#575877](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/575877), [[image]#246185](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-keyring/+bug/246185)) describing the same problem.

None of them have a suitable answer, which leads me to believe there is no way to find out what application is asking you to unlock the keyring.

Comment: please see my revised answer and video

Comment: thanks for the bug link, I've add a link to the upstream bug here and on the unix question -  https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=574315 and requested comments from the developers here

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you've changed your password recently?

In order to see what passwords are stored in your keyring, go to "Passwords and Encryption Keys" in system -> preferences (I think - I always uninstall it as a security risk).

In that application (called Seahorse by the way), click on the "Login" keychain and either change the password on that to match your current password, or remove the password from that keychain altogether by changing it to a blank password (you'll get a warning about using "unsafe storage").

Answer (score 1):

Okay, Goto Your Home folder **Places > Home Folder** And Press `CTRL-H` to show hidden files then navigate to `.gnome2/keyrings`. Look at **default.keyring**. If it is there or there is some sort of file called 'default' then Look at it and that is the app causing you all this issue.

Comment: Both of the files you mentioned are there. `default` contains the string `default`. and `default.keyring` seems to contain only binary data.

Comment: There is a file on my laptop, I will boot it up and see what it is called and then get back you you with it. I could also post a example of what it says in the name part.

Comment: On my laptop there is no binary files :/

Answer (score 1):

You could, alternatively delete your keyring folder and Restart. That should get rid of the Password box. It will not break anything as It recreates itself using default settings :)

Answer (score 0):

Run System Monitor from **System - Administration** and check which application is throwing the prompt.

Comment: When the prompt appears I can't press anything on the screen, including the `System` menu.

Answer (score 0):

Hi 
The key ring dialog pops up whenever ubuntu finds a wireless network.It is utility to save your secret network credentials like password etc.You can change the settings from system> Administration> Keyring manager.(I think you can  find the manager here)(I don't remember the exact location sorry)

Comment: um...if it prompts on finding wireless networks and subsequently joins it is network-manager given the default package selection.  I already noted this in a previous answer