# how do I know what process requires the keyring to be unlocked

Tags: 11.04, keyrings, gnome-keyring

At login the keyring always asks me to unlock it. It drives me crazy and cannot find which process triggers this. Is there any way to figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu stopped showing the offending process because it's a security fault.

Some workarounds are:
- set the keyword password to blank (VERY unsafe, they're stored as plaintext!)
- If you don't have autologin, you delete the Default keyring and re-add your passwords to the 'login' keyring so that when you login you unlock the entire keyring all at once. If you have autologin you can't do this.

Similar question over here (askubuntu): [An application asks to unlock the keyring on startup, but it doesn't say which one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21645/an-application-asks-to-unlock-the-keyring-on-startup-but-it-doesnt-say-which-o)

Their problem was network manager.

Comment: Can you explain why showing the user what process wants to access the keyring is a security problem and/or include links to such an explanation? It seems unlikely that allowing a user to know what is happening on their system is a security problem.

Comment: You know what, I can't find the link any more, but I remember reading it. I don't see how it's a security fault either.

What I did find was this ideas request, which suggests that you may in fact be able to see which program sends the request using `dbus` or looking at the `gnome-keyring` log (I haven't the foggiest how to do either): http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/27040/

Comment: It might be a network manager issue, but actually this is happening on KDE. My problem is that for some reason gnome applications starting up on my KDE session and I dont know why and which. I have an another question regarding that, http://askubuntu.com/questions/80998/gnome-autostart-items-start-on-kde but no answers yet :(