# Lubuntu Openbox Autostart GUI Application

Tags: lubuntu, autostart, openbox

I'd like to autostart a Qt GUI application using Lubuntu/Openbox, using a root-only account.

I've added the command into:

`/etx/xdg/openbox/autostart`

And:

`/root/test`

Grepping for test shows that the application runs, but the application window is not being drawn in foreground - I think it's hidden somewhere, because I notice a short blip on startup.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: That's because you **really, really** should know what you're doing to run a GUI as root (totally not recommended: I haven't done that in the last year or so), so please reword your question as to what you need and we'll tell you what to do...  ;-)

Comment: It's for an embedded device that runs totally separated from the rest of the world. There is only one fullscreen app running (mine) and that's about it. Not quite sure what kind of rewording you want me to do.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/114358/344926) answer...

Comment: Well, that's what I did, the autologin works and openbox as well as my app are started. But my appwindow is not brought to the foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a user and added the line

```
/home/myuser/myguiapp &
```

to /home/myuser/.config/openbox/autostart

Running under root caused problems unrelated to the question itself.