# Automatic unlocking of keyring?

Tags: 11.04, security, gnome-keyring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot/875#875)

I like the idea of gnome-keyring, but having it ask for the unlock password after every startup kinda defeats the purpose. If I log in with my password I already authenticated myself. Can I make gnome-keyring unlock automatically on login?

(I know this lessens the security and it's a completely conscious decision).

Comment: Normally logging in does unlock your keyring. Have you changed your password? Changing your password requires an step to re-associate the keyring with your new password.

Comment: I didn't change my pw. The keyring password can be different (and set up on the first use of the keyring). This always bugged me since every version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I use automatic login on the desktop though... can that be a problem?