# Why does ssh suddenly ask me to "Enter passphrase for key '[home directory]/.ssh/id_rsa'"?

Tags: unity, gnome, ssh, gnupg

Since some weeks `ssh` asks me to `Enter passphrase for key '[home directory]/.ssh/id_rsa'` without any changes to the system. I may have installed updates, but I can't make a connection to a specific one, also not after going through `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

Invoking `gpg-agent` which I recall is somehow related to storing such passwords prints `gpg-agent[24068]: no gpg-agent running in this session` to terminal.

I'm using Unity and see the same issue when using GNOME shell.

After removing a stale `~/.gnupg/gnupg_spawn_agent_sentinel.lock` I could fix and issue where I experienced a ~60 seconds freeze of the screen between login and displaying of the desktop for both Unity and GNOME shell and after every login as well as blocking of email sending in `thunderbird` because the add-on Enigmail was launching `/usr/bin/gpg2 --charset utf-8 --display-charset utf-8 --use-agent --batch --no-tty --status-fd 2 --with-fingerprint --fixed-list-mode --with-colons --list-secret-keys` which (run in a terminal) permanently printed `gpg: waiting for lock (held by 28158) ...`. So, there might be more issues regarding stale locks.

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Does `ps -fp $SSH_AGENT_PID` return anything?

Comment: @steeldriver `SSH_AGENT_PID` isn't set. `ps -A | grep ssh-agent` shows that there're two instances running. The other `SSH_AGENT_[...]` variable is `SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER=gnome-keyring`.

Comment: Apparently duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/983243).

Comment: I've found a [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1033995) that worked for me.