# Loggin In Six Times

Tags: keyrings, seahorse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the ‘default’ keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

Okay, I get why Seahorse makes me log in six times, but is there some way I can do it just once and still have stuff work?