# Unlock Keyring Comes Thrice On Every Boot

Tags: seahorse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the ‘default’ keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

I am running Natty 11.04 on an acer aspire one netbook. It is working fine with just a few issues. One of those is this annoying unlock keyring prompt which comes thrice on every boot. I have my chat accounts, broadcast accounts and ubuntu one account configured and maybe this is why it comes three times. However, I also check the option "Unlock this keyring next time I log in." on all the 3 keyring prompts but it still comes on every boot.

I would like to know how I can stop these annoying prompts to come all the time on each and every boot. Also, if I am not connected to the internet, this prompt comes just once (and not thrice). I dont want to disable any of my services but would like these prompts not to come up and to get these keyrings unlocked everytime I boot my netbook.

Please help ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't concerned about security you can open seahorse. You then change the password of the default one to nothing and maybe the rest. Right mouse click change password type your old one and leave the rest empty it will promt a box if you are sure.

Comment: thanks Rens ! tried that and it worked for me. all my apps are working now and I didnt get ant prompt to unlock any keyring.
though all my passwords are unsafe :P but i am the only one who uses my netbook.. so I guess its not a problem for me :)

Comment: @Swapmil Narendra I had done the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not too concerned about password storage security, then you can simply remove *Passwords and Encryption Keys* program or it's corresponding package, `seahorse`. Alternatively, you can browse it's options to modify it's behavior. I myself am not familiar with it beyond the knowledge that it serves the keyrings, so I cannot recommend any such modifications.

Comment: I am not paranoid about password and security but I would like to keep some programs to manage my keyrings. I dont mind if this prompt comes just once, I am okay with it. But this prompt comes three times and this is what is annoying. Is there a way, I can have this prompt just to come once ?

Comment: @Swapnil, I am sorry, like I said, I am not too familiar with it myself. I'm also runnning a live session right now, so I cannot try and find what options are there for keyrings management. For the wireless connection part, you can simply make the connection available to all users. It will decrease one keyring requirement at least.