# How to remove sign-in (password) fields when i boot up?

Tags: password, keyrings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the ‘default’ keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

I have to sign in five times after opening Ubuntu. Three times for the login keyring which says it is not unlocked until the third sign-in, and twice for the "Default" keyring.

I would like to remove the sign-in process completely as I do not require a locked computer.

Can I safely remove the password app?

Answer (score 4):

1 - Go to **Passwords And Encryption Keys**

2 - On there you have the opportunity to change your default password, enter your old password and then in the field where you would put your new password press **Enter**

You won't be prompted for your password upon logging in any more.

To stop being asked for your password when you Log Out & Log In again go to **Users And Groups** click on **Change Password** and then tick the box labelled **Don't Ask For Password On Login**

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I tried this second instruction-scouser73-and was rid of the sign-in prompts immediately. Thank you. I should have asked this question months ago. The prompts were a real irritation!

Comment: @Namaachi, select this answer to mark the question solved.

Answer (score 0):

Most applications in Ubuntu stores passwords in one place. If you remove that system, the applications would no longer remember your password, so you'd have to type them in manually all the time. Every time you send en email, connect to a wireless network, etc.  In other words; it's not recommendable.

But the keyring should be automatically unlocked when you login, so you should never have to "sign in" more times than at the login screen. You can try this: (translations may be wrong) open "passwords and encryption keys". Right click your keyring and select "Set as default". If that isn't sufficient, then you can try to change the password of the keyring to the password you use to log into the system. I think that should work, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't concerned about security you can open seahorse. You then change the password of the default one to nothing and maybe the rest. Right mouse click change password type your old one and leave the rest empty it will promt a box if you are sure.

Comment: This answer is the same as the http://askubuntu.com/questions/49375/unlock-keyring-comes-thrice-on-every-boot/49409#49409.