# How to auto-unlock Keyring Manager?

Tags: keyrings, unlock

How can I auto-unlock the Keyring Manager in Oneiric Ocelot?
I have found [this description for Intrepid,](http://maketecheasier.com/auto-unlock-keyring-manager-in-ubuntu-intrepid/2009/03/14) but Ocelot looks different so I can't follow the instructions.

I have set up my machine to automatically log in to my account. I am using Unity. I don't mind the lesser security of having the keyring automatically unlocked. (This is a home desktop computer of a simple user, not a missile launch system.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### For 12.04

Thanks to @duffydack's hint, I discovered this:

- In the Password application, right-click the `Passwords: default`
  [image]
- Select `Change password`
- Enter the old password, and *no new password* then click OK
- Confirm to use unencrypted passwords:
  [image]

... But oddly, this does not work: after rebooting, I must enter the password again. Any hints?

Comment: you should change the "default" password , not the "login". greetings

Answer (score 4):

#### For Ubuntu 12.10:

There is a known bug in Seahorse (the password and keys management app) that causing it unable to change login password or automatic keyring unlock setting, with error message `"GDBus.Error: org.freedesktop.Secret.Error.NoSuchObject:The collection does not exist".` See [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/1048484) bug report on Launchpad.

This however has been fixed, so you need to download and install the updated version. You can do this with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install seahorse
```

Open `seahorse` and go to View -> By Keyring. Now right click the login password and choose change. Enter your password when asked for the first time but leave the new password blank. It'll ask for a confirmation and after that you should be good to go.

I found the info [here](http://www.fandigital.com/2012/05/how-to-auto-unlock-keyring-in-ubuntu.html#zupdate).

Comment: 10 years later this still works! Just used this on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Just a bit change: https://askubuntu.com/a/224777

Answer (score 2):

Run the *Password and Encryption Keys* tool from the terminal - type `seahorse` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.