# How to auto-unlock Keyring Manager in 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, keyrings, unlock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to auto-unlock Keyring Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68292/how-to-auto-unlock-keyring-manager)

How can I auto-unlock the Keyring Manager in 12.10?
[This answer for 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/a/68844/5786) doesn't seem to apply because the Keyring Manager looks different in 12.10 so I can't follow the instructions.

I have set up my machine to automatically log in to my account. I don't mind the lesser security of having the keyring automatically unlocked. (This is *still* a home desktop computer of a simple user, not a missile launch system.)