# What do I need for "Passwords & Encryption keys application"?

Tags: 11.10, keyrings

I installed a command line system for Ubuntu 11.10 then installed GNOME Shell and other applications over. I enabled auto login but is always asked to unlock login keyring. I need  to use "Passwords & Encryption keys" application to fix that [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot). But I can't access the app, possibly because I don't have it installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Passwords & Encryption" application is the unusually named `seahorse`

You can check that it is installed by typing `seahorse` at the command-line to launch it.

You can install the application via:

```
sudo apt-get install seahorse
```

This is actually a GUI app front-end to GPG that looks like this:

[image]

Thus if you want to stick to the command line you could just install `gnupg` and `gnome-keyring` - but you will need to manipulate `gnupg` via its command-line interface (`man gnupg`).

Obviously, the GUI front-end is easier!