# Unlock Login Keyring problem - ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: keyrings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

I was using my ubuntu 12.04 without any problem. Suddenly when I tried to connect to a vpn, the Unlock Login Keyring window appeared. I tried my user password, also my vpn password and none of them were accepted. Every time I try to change any of my vpn settings the window will appear again. It will be gone after many times of cancellation. How can I get rid of this window forever?!