# Problem Unlocking Keyring on login

Tags: 12.04, keyrings

I have a problem with unlocking the keyring.

The problem is that every time when login, a window pops up and ask's for password to unlock the key ring.

How can this problem be solved?, such that the keyring unlocks automatically when I login.

Comment: plz check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/134292/unlock-login-keyring-problem-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Comment: @Munish.. I refered that answer, but it is'nt working with mi though! I made another keyring (say keyring1), and made it default too, but the same problem is arising for this new "keyring1". So my problem is'nt solved. Also when the unlock keyring window pop's I'm not able select the "Automaticaly unlock keyring after login".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

Comment: Also in the above question try the other answer.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/134292/unlock-login-keyring-problem-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot

Answer (score 2):

I have loaded up my older desktop with Ubuntu 12.04 and changed the administrator from myself, michael, to my son, Tony! I also changed the administrator password to one I knew he would always use from the one I normally use for myself.

I now get a keyring authentication banner which comes up asking to authenticate but none of the passwords will work, either my own old password, nor his, nor 'none'!

I now have a computer which is fixed in time and space as I cannot update or add or remove software.

How can I annul the password requirements and start afresh?

Do I wipe the computer clean with a hard drive eraser and start again??

Answer (score 0):

open passwords and keys then

[image]

[image]

Then you need to enter your current password (old password). Don't enter any password for your new one, or leave it blank.

You need to confirm that you will store unencrypted password. If you are sure that it is what you want, then just click "Use Unsafe Storage" button.