# Unlock Login Keyring is coming everytime I am logging in

Tags: 11.10, login, startup, keyrings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the ‘default’ keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

Every time I log in into Ubuntu a window comes titled "Unlock Login Keyring" and asks for some password. The problem is when I enter my password it doesn't accepts it.

1. What is login keyring?
2. If it isn't asking about my user account password then which password is it asking about?
3. I don't want to come it everytime I login. How do I make it go away?