# How to prevent "unlock login keyring" pop up window on login?

Tags: login, 12.10, keyrings

Every time I log into Ubuntu 12.10 it shows a pop up window prompting me to "unlock login keyring". How do I prevent that popup?

Suggestions presented on this site did not work on Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Did you try the answer by @ohnMilton from http://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot ?  ***What didn't work?***

Comment: did you try the command line solution in the link provided by @david6 ?

Comment: Yes, I tried all the solutions from that link. When I launch "seahorse" or "Passwords and Keys" it does not give me an option to change the password anymore. This is in Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to go to Menu -> View -> "By keyring".

Comment: turns out I can't change the password in Ubuntu 12.10 preventing one from changing the password: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/1048484

Comment: seahorse-3.6.2 fixes this issue

Comment: This question should not have been closed (how is it off-topic!?). The answer is in @user99305's comment above. There is a bug in 12.10's seahorse preventing users from fixing this problem.

Comment: For those wanting to fix this bug *now* rather than waiting for the update to be pushed to the -updates repository, simply install the appropriate "(proposed)" package from this page: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+package/seahorse

Comment: the package has been pushed to -updates repository.