# How to disable password prompt for default keyring?

Tags: 12.10, keyrings, gnome-keyring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the ‘default’ keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 64Bit.

How to disable `ubuntu enter password for keyring default to unlock` prompt ? Every time I open Chrome or ubuntu software center, this annoying window jump out.

I have being searching online for a long time,  most of the  answers  are like

1. delete `~/.gnome2/keyring XX`   , but I don't have such directory or
2. go to `password and keys` , disable some option, but this window is empty in my case, very strange , even I add a new `password keyring`, it is still empty.

None of these methods works in my case.

I will be very appreciate if you can help

Comment: Regarding the empty window, have you tried clicking "View", "By Keyring" menu?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter your password keyring as it wants you to enter it so it can access the internet. It does it my computer. So if you don't want to access the internet, then exit the window.

Comment: thanks . But I didn't set any password. even I enter a random number, it still prompt out next time when I open the chrome

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't set a password, just type nothing. Just click ok. The window is just making sure you ment to access the internet. The answers on the internet do obviously do not work.