# How do I make Empathy match my keyring with my password?

Tags: password, empathy, keyrings, gnome-keyring, seahorse

I changed my password a few months ago from the password I first used when I installed Ubuntu on my machine. I tried to add a Google Talk account to Empathy, but every time Empathy gives me a message saying the following:

> Enter password to unlock your login keyring
>
> > The password you use to log in to your computer no longer matches that of your login keyring.

I do not remember my original password and I'm not sure if I should go to Prefrences > Passwords and Keys and delete my login password or if there is a way to change the keyring so that it matches up with my current password.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the password you originally used with the keyring, then you cannot change it to your new login password. You'll have to delete it and have it create a new one for you.

Comment: So how do I delete the keyring? All is see listed is password:login when I open up Passwords and Keys.