# `sudo` asks for password even when I have no password set?

Tags: login, password, sudo

I removed the password from my account using the "User Accounts" window and then on running `sudo`, it prompted me for a password, even when i didn't have one. I tried pressing enter without entering anything but it didn't help.

Also I couldn't unlock my account to set a new password in the "User Accounts" window in "System Settings" because it kept prompting for a password and wouldn't except an empty string, just like `sudo`. I then finally set a new password using `passwd`.

Is this a bug which shouldn't be happening? How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Did you try to logout and then login again?

Comment: @NikosGr resetting the password using `passwd` solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you must remove the need for a password to use sudo, you can edit the `/etc/sudoers` file using `sudo visudo` command.

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

and add `NOPASSWD:ALL` for sudoers group as shown above

Comment: does this also stop the keyring prompts at the start?

Comment: for key ring see the different answers to this question depending on your version of ubuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot