# Can't sudo after removing password from administrator account

Tags: 13.10, password, sudo

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 64bit.
In the "System Settings"->"User Accounts" I chose the "Login without a password".
This was my only administrator account, so according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/281093/252848), I encountered [bug #1168749](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1168749), meaning I can't authenticate, not in the terminal and not in the GUI. I tried all of these answers:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/152617
- https://askubuntu.com/a/70445
- https://askubuntu.com/a/136537
- http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo
- https://askubuntu.com/a/194760/252848
- https://askubuntu.com/a/441575/252848

After the first two I was again able to authenticate in the GUI, but still can't sudo in the terminal after trying all these answers and solutions..
Anyone knows how to fix this bug?

**edit**

Actually I was wrong, I can sudo (silly mistake, my bad).
I just kept trying to enter su and it said:

```
su: Authentication failure
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to use sudo in the terminal? Please edit your question adding any error messages exactly as they are printed.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, I can sudo, but when I press su it says: su: Authentication failure with the same password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you're describing is normal, because the root account is locked by default in Ubuntu. If you need an interactive root shell you should use `sudo -i` instead of `su`

For further information, see the discussion at [RootSudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)