# How to disable the "unlock your keyring" popup?

Tags: gnome-keyring

I read through all the related answers, but they do not apply to **Ubuntu 14.04**.

I have no **.gnome2** folder and no **Passwords and Encryption** keys item in the system settings. I tried to crawl through every possible menu, but I could not find out how to do it.

The popup usually pops out when I start **Chromium**.

Comment: Exactly what answers you read and what is the dialog that appears? Google Chrome now has a thingy about an API keys, which could be the reason of the dialog.

Comment: @Braiam The popup is "Enter password to unlock your login keyring\n The login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer.". But it is ok, the accepted answer solved the problem.

Comment: @gsamaras The question you suggest is slightly different. It asks about popup at boot, while I ask about regular popups, mainly during the start of Chromium.

Comment: I agree @MartinDrozdik (you got my upvote already:) )

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot

Comment: if i remember, when it prompt to set an keyring password, i've entered an empty password. Then it never bodered me again :D

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Fire up "User Accounts", set "automatic login" to "off". At startup you will be asked your user/password only once; popups like "unlock keyring" will never pester you again.

Comment: Not true unless you seek out the keyring and tell it to use the "login" keyring instead of the "default" keyring. :P

Comment: I have never, never set my user account to automatic login . . . ever

Comment: this is not true. I never had automatic login on and get the same problem, turned it on/off and it made no difference at all. ubuntu 14.04.03

Comment: It is not the solution, because I want to have automatic login and don't want to see login keying

Comment: This is a workaround, not a solution for those that want automatic login.

Comment: This did not work - automatic logins are off for all user accounts and I still get the popup

Comment: I think this workaround does not work well. To solve the problem, you may instruct Chrome to avoid the keyring with the option the option `--password-store=basic`

Comment: What is "User Accounts"? Can you add the program name?

Answer (score 60):

This is for 14.04

1. Open the password/keyring manager from settings (or run it directly - seahorse)
2. Ensure Menu > View > By Keyring is ticked.
3. In the sidebar, under 'passwords' create a new keyring 'Unprotected' (or re-use an existing keyring, e.g. 'Default', but NOT 'Login' because that will make everything unprotected which you probably don't want)
4. Right-click the new keyring, and 'set as default'
5. Right-click the new keyring and set its password as empty (only needed if you adopted an existing keyring)
6. In the 'Login' keyring, delete the network secret for your wifi.
7. Go to the network manager and add the network again - its secret should appear in the default keyring, which has no password.
8. Set the default keyring back to Login.

Comment: xfce does not have this option in the menu

Comment: done 1-5 steps on 14.04 and the problem - seems gone: popups appeared in various apps, like IDE when entering passwords inside, ssh clients and so on. Thanks!

Comment: Under Kubuntu 14.04.5, how do I open the password/keyring manager?  "User Accounts" under "System Settings" doesn't do it.

Answer (score 35):

**About the Chrome and the keyrings**

This problem occurs because Chrome wants to store usernames/passwords in the keyring (so they are encrypted). Therefore, every time you open Chrome, it tries to unlock the keyring.

Please note that, in Linux, [Chrome can use different keyring types](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/security/faq.md#Does-the-Password-Manager-store-my-passwords-encrypted-on-disk) for the passwords you store in the browser:

- **Basic keyring:** where Chrome stores passwords in a local SQLite database called “Login Data” (`$HOME/.config/chromium/Default/Login Data`). There, the passwords are unencrypted.
- **Desktop keyrings:** (i.e., **gnome-keyring** or **KWallet**) where Chrome stores the passwords in the services provided by GNOME or KDE. It stores the encrypted passwords in a special database that must be unlocked before it can be used.

To disable the “unlock your keyring” popup permanently, you may (1) instruct Chrome to avoid the desktop keyrings or (2) create a desktop keyring or modify the default one using [Seahorse](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Seahorse) (for GNOME) or [KDE Wallet Manager](https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_Wallet_Manager) (for KDE).

> You may instruct Chrome to avoid the desktop keyrings and use a local database. If you do that, Chrome will not try to unlock the keyring again. However, every time you instruct Chrome to "remember a password", [the password will be stored in plan-text](https://rtfm.co.ua/en/chromium-linux-keyrings-secret-service-passwords-encryption-and-store/#Chromium_without_a_keyring) in the your local computer. An expert user may get access to your passwords in plan-text if you use this alternative. This solution is recommended only if you do not ask Chrome to remember your passwords.

---

**Instructing Chrome to avoid the keyring**

To run Chrome without using the keyring, you may use the option `--password-store=basic`:

```
$ google-chrome --password-store=basic
```

---

**Modifying the Chrome launcher (icon) to avoid the keyring**

Considering that you usually run Chrome doing a doble-click on an icon, you must [change the command for the icons you use](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2017/12/20/google-chrome-asks-password-unlock-login-keyring/) to include the additional option to run chrome in this way all the time. You may edit (1) the global launcher in the `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` 
 folder or (2) the personal launcher file located in the `~/.local/share/applications/` directory.

1. Edit the launcher file. For instance, using `gedit`

   ```
    sudo vi /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
   ```
2. Modify the `Exec=` line to include the `--password-store=basic` option

   ```
    Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome  --password-store=basic (and any other option you want)
   ```

Comment: `password-store=basic` means   that all you Chrome password will be stored in plain text which is unsafe. This answer isn't  good at all.

Comment: It is a good answer if you do not store passwords in chrome

Comment: `--password-store=basic` also works for other applications like opera. Similar to Marco I don't want to store passwords in my browser so this is a reasonable option for me and possibly others.

Comment: Whilst running `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable  --password-store=basic` does solve the issue, editing the .desktop files you mentioned does not. At least not in 18.10 The "solution" is to set an empty password on your "Login" keyring (not your user).

Comment: didn't work for me, but the seahorse solution (different answer) does.

Comment: Over six years on and Chrome is still causing problems. I had the exact same problem in Mint 20.1. My opinion is - if a program causes problems and there are alternatives, remove it. There are plenty of alternative browsers, so just remove Chromium (Chrome). No other program causes this popup for me, so I just removed it. Sorted.

Answer (score 28):

Just remove it's file as a charm:

```
rm ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring
```

Comment: What are the implications of this? What is the file responsible for?

Comment: Thanks. I was prompted to create new keyring after that - had to set it to empty password, then popup warned that passwords will be stored as plain text. Pressed ok, and no more popups, yay.

Comment: That helped, Thank you

Comment: This was the only answer that actually helped.  Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: 2021 : Linux Mint - Fix Works  !

Comment: Best answer for me.

Comment: Works perfectly for Ubuntu 20.04! Now it logs in Auto and connects to network. Since it was running some Server Applications this is required to make it "Wife/Family" proof. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

It started popping up (after every logout) ever since I logged-in with new password.

In my case possword had been changed during my medical leave and once I came back, I changed the new password to my old login password (I remember that easily). It ended.

I changed my password using:

```
sudo passwd vimal
```

gave changed password for `sudo`, the current login and then new password (my old password, typed twice).

Shut-down.

And it did not come again!

Answer (score 2):

Just remove / turn off your online accounts when not needed. I had the same problem and I solved this by removing my online account.

Comment: What online accounts is this talking about?

Comment: I guess it's these: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/accounts.html.en

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is rather old, but for me the cause was WiFi networks. The configuration utility for NetworkManager (right-click on `nm-applet` and choose "Edit Connections...") offers two ways to save a WiFi password - one is to use a keyring and the other is to save it internally. I had switched from using a keyring to saving it internally because I preferred the convenience of the latter method, however the password was still saved in the keyring which then wanted unlocking.