# ubuntu 14.04 wifi frustrations

Tags: wireless

I haven't used ubuntu for a while - it has been a couple years that I gave up because last time I used it I had many frustrations with basic functionality (wifi/sleep on laptop close) . I have a brand new dell precision running 14.04 from the factory and was hoping that things would be better but in 2016 I am still having wifi problems.

- I am sitting here with an IP address, fully authenticated and connected and cannot access the internet, out of nowhere wifi just drops off. I cannot ping the DNS's or the even the gateway. dmesg, syslog, nm-tool reveal nothing useful.
- ~50% of the time it does not even try to connect to my work network even though I have selected "automatically connect when available"
- I tell NetworkManager to connect with a saved username and password and yet it asks me for the password every time, it requires me to type it in twice occasionally before it 
  authenticates.
- It also asks if I want to ignore the lack of a valid cert, of which I click the box "Dont ask me again" - it asks me again, every time.

NetworkManager really is terrible - it has never worked on anything I have used and requires constant tweaking to keep it functional. I had better results from conf files with slackware back in the 00's.

So yeah I am using an intel wifi card and all the drivers are up to date that I know of. What exactly is the issue here? Why cannot I not maintain a connection? Why does NetworkManager not remember anything I tell it?

I posted below an image of the common questions section - maybe NetworkManager should be replaced with something easier to use!?

[image: I posted a picture of the common questions, the amount of wifi problems is obvious]

Comment: hard to know. Best solution of course is to purchase linux compatible hardware or a computer with linux pre installed. If you are having a problem with your hardware, we need to know what it is to see if there is a potential fix. Personally I purchased a linux compatible wireless usb card for about $10 was faster and easier then debugging by linux incompatible wireless.

Comment: I have a Dell precision developer edition - It came with ubuntu 14.04 pre-installed.

Comment: so, identify your hardware as a start. I can not tell from your question the extent of your problem (hardware, wireless, network manager, or storing passwords). - http://askubuntu.com/questions/495957/how-to-disable-the-unlock-your-keyring-popup for example.