# Installed Chrome, Keyring Popup

Tags: login, chromium, keyrings

Auto signin worked fine on boot until I installed Chromium.  Now the computer signs in on boot, but when i start Chrome, there is a popup asking me enter my keyring ... it gets tedious. Auto signin is all set up under 'users' correctly, so i don't know what is going on. I have seen a workaround that involves setting a blank password.  Not keen on that because of security issues.  Anyone got any other ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you sign in, it unlocks the gnome keyring used for storing encrypted passwords. The auto sign in skips unlocking this gnome keyring, so when a program requests to use it, you still have to sign in. Turning off the automatic login shall remove these pop-ups. There is also an additional way of disabling the pop-up in the second answer of this post: [How to disable the "unlock your keyring" popup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/495957/how-to-disable-the-unlock-your-keyring-popup)

Comment: It is a good workaround, but currently i am only entering the password once, which would pretty much be the same as having to do it at boot up, so I will just live with. Cheers for the help.