# Why is it so hard to change the account password?

Tags: login, google-chrome, password

I recently decided to change the password on my Ubuntu 19.10 account on my laptop. When I did however, I suddenly had this message popping up saying that I had to enter the password for my 'login key' as it did not unlock. I put in the new password which it would not accept.

I tried ignoring this until it kept popping up more and more. Especially when opening Chrome browser.
I found some instructions online telling me to go through 'seahorse' and change it there. This did not work and also, Chrome started forgetting my passwords and not logging me in automatically.
A long story short, I had to use Timeshift to go back to before I tried changing my password. This fixed it but I am now back to having my old password which I have had for a while and is probably a security risk now because I have had it for so long.

Is there any easier work around to changing the password? I don't remember it being this difficult on previous versions of Ubuntu so why has it changed?

Comment: This *feels* like it's an issue with your keyring sync. I suspect [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/495957/how-to-disable-the-unlock-your-keyring-popup) might be something worth trying; more appropriately, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1034053/212930) for Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method to change your password is `passwd user` (where user is your account name), but from the sounds of things it hasn't updated your keyring password - so it wants your old password. If that's the case, check out [How to recover/reset forgotten Gnome Keyring Password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password#65294) on how to remove the keyring or recover.

If you know your password (and it doesn't sycn like it should), try the [following answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1128/119606) from Ask Unix:

> If you change your password through the GUI, it should automaticly
>   synchronize the keyring that stores your WiFi passwords etc. too.
>
> You can also always change it from seahorse's control panel
>   ("Encryption & Keyrings" or something like that in the Preferences).

Lastly (and this has all been a hunch to your issue) you can disable the keyring entirely, with [the following answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/495957/how-to-disable-the-unlock-your-keyring-popup):

> Fire up "User Accounts", set "automatic login" to "off". At startup
>   you will be asked your user/password only once; popups like "unlock
>   keyring" will never pester you again.