# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS disable on boot: unlock keyring for an application who wants to acces "Default Keyring" but is locked

Tags: login, password, 20.04, keyrings

I'm new to Ubuntu (Linux) on desktop, 3 days ago I left Windows 10!

How can I disable at boot: unlock keyring for an application who wants to access "Default Keyring" but is locked?

[image]

I have set auto-login, but this annoying popup it's driving me crazy, everything is freeze till enter the password on this popup.

I've [search online answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/495957/how-to-disable-the-unlock-your-keyring-popup) on Ask Ubuntu and [itsfoss](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-keyring/) regarding disable keyring but no success on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Passwords and Keys utility from Gnome Dash (Pic 1)(I don't now why, but I always start this program on GnuPG keys. Click arrow in top left corner(Pic 2)). Right click on Login and choose Change Password.Input original password (the password you set when user created), set new password to be empty.(Non secure)(Pic 3)

Pic 1:

[image: Pic 1]

Pic 2:

[image: Pic 2]

Pic 3:

[image: Pic 3]

Comment: `Passwords and Keys` does not appear for me with Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by selecting "show trusted" in Default keyring settings of "Password and Keys" app

[image: Default keyring settings]