# Is it possible to prevent Brave Browser from asking for keyring access?

Tags: password, browser, keyrings, brave

I recently installed the Brave Browser using the method on their website (I do not believe I used snap; I believe it was via apt). Every time I open it, the browser asks for me to enter my password so it can access my keyring. I do not want to do this.

Every time I start the browser, I have to "cancel" out of the keyring dialogue three times before it lets me go about my business.
Is there a way I can prevent it from asking this question again?

I do not use auto-log in.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can write an AppArmor profile that prevents Brave Browser from accessing the Keys & Password service in the first place. That will not be easy, however. You should start here: https://www.linux.org/threads/securing-ubuntu-with-apparmor.26523/

Comment: Did you add Brave keyring?

Comment: @JoKeR I used the installation instructions from here https://brave-browser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-brave.html#linux and while the word "keyring" appears in the command, I do not know if it is installed or not. brave-keyring --version does not return anything. Do you know how to install it?

Comment: I try to figure it out too. Very annoying

Comment: The keyring in the link is talking about the keyring for your Linux system's package manager.  You're adding the Brave gpg key they use for signing packages to your trusted list.  It has nothing to do with the popup where Brave tries to access your system keyring to store saved passwords (even if that function is disabled in Brave).

Comment: I have had the same annoying problem since I just installed Ubuntu 22.04. Brave also has a "Could not sync Brave on your devices" since "Brave could not access your operating system's safe storage" now. I guess there is a problem with the default keychain integration.

Answer (score 3):

Check [How to disable the "unlock your keyring" popup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/495957/how-to-disable-the-unlock-your-keyring-popup)

There's many ways.

I choose mine: remove `gnome-keyring`, I don't need it:

```
apt remove gnome-keyring
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link... But what are the implications of removing gnome-keyring?

Comment: None if you don't use it explicitly.

Comment: Most answers I'm finding seem to be to either remove your system keyring, or make the system keyring passwordless.  Both are completely unreasonable options for the large number of people that do actually use the keyring for saving passwords on their Linux system.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to the following folder:
home/.local/share/keyrings

You can delete the respective default keyring file.

.local is a hidden folder, so you will not appear in file folder until you select show hidden files option (located in the little box with the three horizontal lines).

Answer (score -1):

**Brave** V1.45.131 installed on Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS:

Settings → Autofill → Passwords → Disable offer to save password

Answer (score -2):

Settings > Additional settings dropdown > Autofill > Offer to save passwords

I tried that process!