# Is there a way to not have a default keyring?

Tags: password, keyrings, gnome-keyring

Perhaps I misunderstand what the keyring is, but it seems like it appears when either an ssh key of a password might be required. I manage my passwords and my ssh keys with third party programs, I don't want ubuntu to manage either of them.

I also really don't like that popup that grabs focus. I hit cancel every time till it goes away. Without it, either my ssh keyring unlocks things automatically, or the password field will wait until I am done with other tasks and ready to enter my password. When my ssh keyring needs a password it asks via CLI, which is much better.

I have looked at this question; [How to disable the "unlock your keyring" popup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/495957/how-to-disable-the-unlock-your-keyring-popup)
but it seems to be setting an empty password, and commentators point out that is insecure. I'm not really sure what this keyring will get access to, I'd rather it didn't have access to anything, but I may have misunderstood what it is.

If I give it a blank password what does it get access to? Can I prevent it from having access to anything?

Answer (score 0):

The key ring is for mostly the machine usage, it controls access to things that require root user privileges. Disable it by making the password blank anyone can do anything any time they want on your machine without a password. As you have discovered an OS that takes security seriously is inconvenient to use at times.

Comment: Can I make it so that if a command requires sudo I must manually execute it with sudo? For example, skype asks, and I don't intend to run skype with sudo, so I'm glad I didn't give skype access. It seems like the Ubuntu 18 approach was just to have stuff fail if it needed sudo and I didn't launch it with sudo, which was preferable.

Comment: http://positon.org/gnome-autologin-and-unlocking-the-keyring-with-a-password < this seems to indicate that the default keyring is not capable of granting programs sudo, and the only thing is must have is the wifi password. Is that correct?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1314601/666427 < this answer thinks that it gets more passwords than the wifi automatically, but that it can't grant root user privileges.