# What is the least information that the default keyring can hold?

Tags: password, keyrings, gnome-keyring

I don't want the default keyring to store my passwords. I have another solution that I like better.

This post; http://positon.org/gnome-autologin-and-unlocking-the-keyring-with-a-password
seems to indicate that the only thing the default keyring must have is the wifi password. Is this true?

Will a default keyring have the ability to grant programs sudo access?

How can I verify that the default keyring only has the wifi keys?

Answer (score 1):

The keyring has more than just WIFI passwords, any program can store passwords there.

Some programs that store passwords in the keyring by default:

- `chromium`
- `vlc` (network streams)
- `nextcloud` client
- `nautilus` for network connections (e.g. smb passwords)
- `gpg`
- `ssh-agent`
- `Ubuntu` online accounts
- ...

By default, the keyring gets unlocked when you login but it won't grant any program `sudo` access.

Run `seahorse` (GUI tool) to see what is saved there.

---

To disable automatic unlock when you login, remove these lines from files in `/etc/pam.d/`:

```
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

But I would suggest not to do that, rather tell your programs not to use the `keyring`.

Comment: Can this behavior be prevented? Like I said, I have my own password management in place already. In particular I don't want the ssh agent saving passwords there. Any way to prevent that one?

Comment: That is fine, ssh-agent will store only passwords if you tell it to do so.