# Why am I always asked to create a new keyring?

Tags: password, keyrings, 22.10

Every time I have restarted mysystem, and use an application that might need a password (Thunderbird, Vivaldi, etc.) I am asked to create a password for *new* keyring.

It doesn't matter if I create the keyring with an empty password, the next boot I'm asked again.

[image]

I don't want to set a password, and I don't want to see this multiple times every day (once for each app that uses passwords).

I'm using an up-to-date 22.10 system (did a `dist-upgrade` yesterday).

Still didn't work after an upgrade to 23.04 this spring. I'm leaning toward doing a fresh reinstall for 23.10 to hopefully get rid of it.

Comment: Does this work for you https://askubuntu.com/a/1181666/1198244 , https://askubuntu.com/a/875/1198244

Comment: @UtkarshChandraSrivastava The first did not, the second was simply too old to apply.

Comment: Search passwords and keyring  in app menu , right click on login and then change password it should work.

Comment: @UtkarshChandraSrivastava Didn't help, I am still asked to create new keyrings.

Comment: For me, it seems to have helped to make one of the existing keyrings the default one. (Via Gui: Search for "Passwords and Keys", left hand side on passwords, right click -> "Set as default")

Comment: @cis I tried that, setting the "Login" keyring as default. Then I started a program that normally puts up four requests, and this time I got *none*! Seems to work, so please write an answer that I can upvote and accept. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to help to set one of the existing keyrings as "default".

In order to do so via Gui:

- In "Activities", search for "Passwords and Keys"
- On the left hand side, in the "passwords" section, right click on the keyring you want to use
- "Set as default")

[image]

Comment: While this seems to solve the problem I ask about (and hence the accept) I still need to unlock the keyring once on boot. So it's a *lot* better, as I now only have one dialog at start, not many spread out over the uptime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

- Go to Activities/Applications(Whatever!)
- search for Seahorse(Password and Encryption)
- Go back if you're on the GnuPG keys section else click on login and click delete if you don't want the popup or else you may click change password and set it to none.

Comment: Tried and doesn't work.