# Constantly being asked for unknown password

Tags: password

I'm using Xubuntu. Whenever I log in, and periodically when I'm using the computer, I'll be asked to enter my password to access the keyring. The problem is that I don't remember ever setting this password. I've tried all my common passwords and none seem to work. So, is there anyway to either a) disable this from happening - so that I won't be asked to enter the password that's unknown to me or b) reset the keyring password to something that I actually know? Thanks!

Comment: do you have auto log-in enabled?

Comment: Yeah, it's enabled

Comment: What version of Xubuntu do you use?

Comment: that is why it asks to unlock the keyring then, If you forgot your password -  http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: I'm using 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer should be the same to the problem like this in ubuntu.

Here is the link
[How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

Hope this helps. Please vote if it helps:)

Comment: Why you give a down vote? Can't you just state what u didn't like about my answer and I will change it. By down voting you are ruining me and making it worse for yourself

Comment: Plus in this link it shows u how to access keyring without an answer

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted you. But I just read the link and it looked helpful, so I'll give you an upvote. I appreciate the help. Thank you. Edit: I guess I'm not allowed to upvote due to insufficient reputation. :( Sorry.

Comment: Or you could just select this with the green tick for best answer, only if you truly thought it was good

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the password for the keyring you set for your user account at install. The password you use to log in to your account if you had auto login off.

Answer (score 0):

For Russian-speaking.

Для русскоговорящих.

Подобную проблему я решил почти 5 лет назад, вот запись с картинками в моем блоге: [Пароль для связки ключей](http://tm-experimental.blogspot.ru/2010/12/blog-post.html)

I solved this problem about 5 years ago, the link points to my blog post (in Russian) with explanations.

Comment: Ну тут вообще то желательно на английском выкладывать , и в постах лучше хот бы в двух словах описать как решать проблему. А ссылки на сайты простл так сильно не приведствуются. Учти на будущее

Comment: @Serg Я как бы в курсе, по сути моя ссылка повторяет приведенные здесь способы решения проблемы.

Comment: Я понимаю. Просто даю совет. Обычно если ответ просто с ссылкой и без инструкций получает минус. Хороший пример - другой ответ на этой же странице , Apad121. Ну а там смотри сам. Я просто советую

Comment: Тёзка, "давайте без давайте", ладно? Как раз, чтобы избежать подобного я и сделал коммент двуязычным, с дополнительным указанием, что ссылка ведет на запись в блоге, сделанную на русском, посвященную решению этой проблемы. Для не читающего по-русски сразу ясно, что решение там есть, но может быть ему не понятно без перевода