# Google Chromium asks for keyring to unlock 14.04, but I don't want the password to be the same as my ubuntu login

Tags: 14.04, password, chromium, keyrings, seahorse

I don't want this prompt to use my default ubuntu login, I would like this to match the password I would use either on a chromebook, mac, or windows. In other words, similar behavior to the other operating systems.

How would I make it so that I typed in my chromebook login, for example?

[image: Chromium keyring prompt]

Text of the prompt:

"Enter password for keyring 'Chromium' to unlock"
"An application wants access to the keyring 'Chromium', but it is locked"

Comment: The other questions did not ask to 'have a different' password than the login password. Please unmark the duplicate tag as I don't think it is appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Specifically for  14.04**

WARNING: Do not change your password to blank, as other answers have suggested. This could be dangerous.

1.) Run `Password and Keyring` or `seahorse` (if you dont have it installed, you can install it by running following command in teminal `sudo apt install seahorse`)

2.) File -> New (or Ctrl+N)

[image: seahorse, the keyring program for ubuntu]

3.) Name a new 'Password Keyring' as "Chromium"

[image]

4.) Enter your 'Chromium' password.

[image]

End Result is different passwords for your login and your google chrome keyring, keeping them separate.

[image]

Comment: I should note that this functions the same as windows, but in windows it only asks for the password once and stores it for some reason.

Comment: I have created a new keyring, deleted the "Chromium Safe Storage" from the "default" keyring, locked it and restarted Chromium, but it still asks to unlock the "default" keyring.  How do I tell Chromium to use this new keyring I have created?

Comment: Two things: 1) it may be possible you are using 16.04, this Q/A applies only to 14.04 2.) The key should be named 'Chromium' to work, and nothing appears named 'Chromium Safe Storage'. This may be a question in it of itself, and less of a comment.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realized the name has to be exactly "Chromium". I'll try again. I'm actually using Debian, not Ubuntu, but I'm guessing Chromium is the same for both?

Comment: Can you elaborate the solution for Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot?noredirect=1&lq=1