# Lubuntu 14.04 - unlock keyring on login

Tags: lubuntu, keyrings

How do I automatically unlock the keyring at login on my Lubuntu 14.04 system?

There are a lot of answers to this problem on this site and Ubuntu Forums, but none are applicable to a 14.04 Lubuntu system - it appears that the Passwords and Keys dialog has changed significantly since those answers were supplied.

SO -

- answers telling me to tick the box for "Unlock the keyring at login"
  in the Seahorse app do not work, because it is not there.
- answers (like [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2078976)) telling me to tick the box on the "Unlock Keyring" dialog
  box to unlock it at login do not work, because it is not there
- auto-login was never set on this system, so that is not a contributor, and [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/43132/why-do-i-need-to-enter-a-password-for-the-default-keyring-to-unlock) does not apply
- the issue does not arise with Network Manager (like [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1840716)), but rather with Deja-dup
- I do not want an answer that involves removing the keyring password
  entirely - like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

How can this rather basic requirement be met on a Lubuntu 14.04 system?

[edit] - here is the dialog box requesting the keyring unlock.
[image]

Comment: I have Lubuntu 14.04 fully updated but don't have any "unlock the keyring at login" requirement. Could you put up an image of what this keyring looks like? I'm assuming you aren't referring to the vanilla login screen. I too haven't set autologin.

Comment: Also, is this a pure Lubuntu install?

Comment: Yes, it's a pure Lubuntu install from scratch.  The "unlock the keyring" screen does not appear at login, but rather when I start an encrypted Deja-dup backup.

Comment: Deja-dup isn't part of default Lubuntu. And if the unlock screen doesn't appear at login, you could edit your question. As it stands, it appears that the keyring unlock appears at login (as per the first sentence).

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to - my goal is to *unlock the keyring at login automatically*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure, `libpam-gnome-keyring` is installed on your system

```
sudo apt-get install libpam-gnome-keyring
```

Also you should have a login keyring in `~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring`

---Edited by OP to cover another situation.

I installed LXDE on my Ubuntu 14.04 system and started getting this keyring popup again when I took a backup.  `libpam-gnome-keyring` was already installed on this system!  To fix it, I had to add a line of text to two files, like this:

To `/etc/pam.d/passwd` add:

```
password optional pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

And to `/etc/pam.d/login` add:

```
session    optional     pam_gnome_keyring.so        auto_start
```

This will unlock the keyring on login when I log in through LXDE.

Comment: Verified to work on my 64-bit Lubuntu 14.04 install.  Thanks!

Comment: I've been trying to fix this issue from 14.04 and thanks to this answer I've finally fixed it on 16.04. It was driving me crazy!

Comment: On my lubuntu 16.04 `~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring` does not exists. I created it, empty, but above solution does not work. Every time Skype Alpha requires to enter username and password and after that Keyring "Default" dialogue appears.

Comment: After this: "Renaming the folder /home/username/.local/share/keyrings to /home/username/.local/share/keyrings.old and a restart solved my problem. " source: [Mint Community](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/916), Skype Alpha on Lubuntu 16.04 did not ask for Keyring.

Comment: it's simpler to just install seahorse

Comment: On Ubuntu 17.04: after doing what the answer said it didn't work. Turns out that I already created a Default_keyring, which was the default and still kept asking to be unlocked. The solution was to go inside the ~/.local/share/keyrings folder and write `login` in the `default` file. Then I deleted the old Default_keyring, and rebooted, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be relevant to this specific question, but I came across it while experiencing a very similar issue on Ubuntu 19.10 and wanted to share what worked for me in case someone else comes across this while googling like I did:

I tried disabling SSH Key Agent (GNOME Keyring: SSH Agent) under Startup Applications, then rebooted. This *appeared* to have no effect as I still got two prompts immediately on login, which I dismissed. I then noticed that the calendar applet had crashed and was asking if I wanted to submit a report. I put two and two together and went to **Settings > Online Accounts, removed my Google account, and rebooted** again.

---

This appears to have resolved the issue for now. I'll do some further testing by re-enabling the SSH Agent and seeing if I can log back in to my Google account without it causing further problems. I'm assuming it was something to do with my credentials expiring, but need to do some reading to understand it further. I plan on returning to this post and making edits to reflect whatever I'm able to uncover/learn. Hopefully it'll be of use to someone.