# Gnome Keyring does not work anymore on Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, gnome-keyring

EDIT: it seems it does work, but the password are always asked anyway. I have to close anytime the window that asks the password.

I installed Gnome Keyring some month ago for `git`, and it worked well. Now it does not work anymore. It asks me for the key to unlock it, but the stored passwords (printers, internet key...) are **not** used, I have to type them every time.

I'm using it on Lubuntu 14.04

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/666453/lubuntu-14-04-unlock-keyring-on-login

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti: the issue happens even if gnome keyring is already unlocked

Answer (score 0):

1) sudo apt-get install seahorse

2) Open a terminal and type seahorse, or find 'Passwords and Keys' in Preferences menu.

3) Click on the View menu and then click on 'By keyring', this shows a left side bar.

4) In the left side bar, under Passwords, right click on 'default' and choose 'Change Password'.

5) Enter the old password, then the new one twice (as prompted).

6) Reboot to ensure it all works wonderfully well.

Comment: Already tried with no success :)

Comment: sorry, I am out of answers.  Maybe purge and reinstall keyring

Comment: Already done... ^^

Comment: I know this sounds like overkill, but you could always reinstall the whole system and try another distro while you are at it too.  You will need to upgrade soon.  I also was on Lubuntu and remember something like this happened, but seahorse fixed it.  I am now on Mate.  It is much better.  xubuntu is a little lighter than mate, but not much.