# How to stop being asked to unlock "Default Keyring" on logging in?

Tags: gnome, login, password

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and Gnome 3.

Every time I login, I am immediately prompted with:

> Enter password to unlock An application wants to access the keyring Default keyring, but it is locked.

[image: popup]

- How do I prevent this?
- What is application is trying to access this keyring?
- Why is it not unlocked? I am already logged in and it is locked with the same password...

I have tried every answer in [this question][2] but none of them work. That question is about "Seahorse" which I am not using.

Furthermore, in order of answers to [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot/224777#224777)

- Answer 1 does not work because it asks me to go to **Open Applications -> Accessories -> Password and Encryption Keys**  but I do not have **Password and encryption keys**
- Answer 2 does not work because: It is super old (5 Ubuntu versions ago) and I can't access the **Password and Keyring**
- Answer 3 does not work because: It is even older and the interface has changed
- Answer 4 does not work because: **system / Preferences / Passwords and Encryption Keys** does not exist for me

-Answer 5 does not work because it mentions **Open Applications > Accessories > Passwords and Encryption Keys** and this menu does not exist on my system.

etc.

[This question is also similar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666453/lubuntu-14-04-unlock-keyring-on-login) and buried in the comments is this:

> The solution was to go inside the `~/.local/share/keyrings` folder and write `login` in the default file. Then I deleted the old `Default_keyring`, and rebooted, and it worked

However, trying that just creates *2* prompts.  One to create a new password / keyring, and then another to unlock it:

[image: prompt]

So, does anybody have any ideas for the three questions listed above, or mainly just how to fix this on modern Ubuntu (17) and Gnome 3?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I do not think so. I tried all of those answers and they are mainly for LXDE.  None of them work and the answers do not address the three questions I asked.

Comment: One more option: You install Seahorse so that the "Passwords and Keys" application shows up, and then use those answers.

Comment: I have struggled with this problem on many systems.  Those answers - as modified - worked for me.  Best of luck in finding your answer - this should not be as hard as it is.

Comment: Remove the password you added to it.