# Error at system start when autologin is enabled

Tags: startup, 23.10, auto-login

When I boot my Ubuntu 23.10 system with autologin enabled I get the error "Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occured and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again". After I log out, put my password and log back in everything works fine but I'd like to be able to use the autologin. Here is what my system log says right after I log in.

> 04:10:46 seahorse: SoftHSM.cpp(527): Could not load the configuration
>
> 04:10:31 gsd-smartcard: SoftHSM.cpp(527): Could not load the
> configuration
>
> 04:10:29 bluetoothd: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
>
> 04:10:28 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: couldn't unlock the login keyring.
>
> 04:10:28 bluetoothd: Failed to remove UUID: Failed (0x03)
>
> 04:10:15 gsd-smartcard: SoftHSM.cpp(527): Could not load the
> configuration
>
> 04:10:15 systemd: Failed to start org.gnome.Shell@x11.service - GNOME
> Shell on X11.
>
> 04:10:06 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: couldn't unlock the login keyring.
>
> 04:10:05 systemd: Failed to start thermald.service - Thermal Daemon
> Service.
>
> 04:10:01 kernel:  04:10:00 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method
> _SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT0._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND)
> (20230331/psparse-529)
>
> 04:10:00 kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does
> not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem
> 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x201] vs fed40080 f80
>
> 04:10:00 kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does
> not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem
> 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x201] vs fed40080 f80
>
> 04:10:00 kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does
> not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem
> 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x201] vs fed40080 f80

[image: Error]

Comment: Have you tried changing your password or removing your keyring password?

Comment: Removing my keyring password fixed it thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto unlock keyring on auto login without leaving password unencrypted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724313/auto-unlock-keyring-on-auto-login-without-leaving-password-unencrypted)