# I do not want to be asked for a password after being inactive

Tags: password

Every time that I come back to my computer after being inactive (i.e. I am not in front of the computer), Ubuntu is (are?) locked and I am prompted for a password. How to disable this?

---

Note that I have Don't suspend enabled on Power -> Inactive. Also notice that my question differs from [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

Comment: Settings>>Display -- there should be a "Require Password" option there.

Comment: Settings -> Security & Privacy was the answer @Zacharee1, but you almost made it, so if it wasn't for you I wouldn't have found it. Are you going to answer that?

Comment: If you'll let me, I'll put it there :).

Comment: What was the name of the option? I'm not in Ubuntu :/

Comment: `Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Waking from suspend` @Zacharee1. Go on, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under <kbd>Settings</kbd>→<kbd>Security & Privacy</kbd> there is an option to disable requiring the password when the screen is awakened.